# MySQL Connector Cursor Description

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I am trying to insert the column headings from the output of a procedure in front of the results using MySQL connector.

My code is currently:

```
    import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='###', password='###',
                              host='###',
                              port='###',
                              database='new_schema')
if cnx.is_connected():
        print('Connection Established.')
    else:
        print('Connection Failed.')


    def call_new_carer_report():
        cur = cnx.cursor()
        cur.callproc('new_carer_report')
        cur.stored_results()
        for result in cur.stored_results():
            global results
            results = result.fetchall()
        header = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
        rows = [list(i) for i in cur.fetchall()]
        rows.insert(0, header)
        cur.close()
```

I recieve an output correctly with `results` but recieve an error on line:

```
header = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
```

Which States:

```
    header = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring out where I went wrong.

The new function code is:

```
def call_new_carer_report():
    cur1 = cnx.cursor()
    cur1.callproc('new_carer_report')
    cur1.stored_results()
    for result in cur1.stored_results():
        global results1
        results1 = result.fetchall()
    header1 = [i[0] for i in result.description]
    rows1 = [list(i) for i in results1]
    rows1.insert(0, header1)
    print(rows1)
    cur1.close()
```

I realised I was trying to grab the description from the Cursor object and not the stored results.

Answer (score 0):

This error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" is most probably due to an incorrect SQL statement in the query.